# Send messages from within parallel function (parallel or future framework)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I would like to send messages from within a function to the R console during a parallel process using the `parallel` package or the future framework and `pblapply::pblapply()`.

Here is a reprex that does not send any messages to the R console:

```r
# library
library(pbapply)
library(stringi)
library(parallel)

# make fun
fun_func <- function(x){
  cat(paste0("hello world ",x))
  return(paste0("hello world ",x))}


# get data
set.seed(23)
d <- stri_rand_strings(100, 2, '[a-z]')
names(d) <- d

# make cluster
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(3)

# load func
clusterExport(cl, c("fun_func"))

# run function
pblapply(cl=cl,X=d,FUN=fun_func) -> res

# stop cluster
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

# show res
head(res)
#> $of
#> [1] "hello world of"
#> 
#> $is
#> [1] "hello world is"
#> 
#> $vl
#> [1] "hello world vl"
#> 
#> $zz
#> [1] "hello world zz"
#> 
#> $vz
#> [1] "hello world vz"
#> 
#> $ws
#> [1] "hello world ws"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Update:**
I just learned that it [mitght be hard to get console message in Windows/RStudio](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781784394004/1/ch01lvl1sec09/the-r-parallel-package). However, logging the messages with [`ParallelLogger`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ParallelLogger/vignettes/Logging.pdf) might be an option.
Unfortunaltely I could not implement it.

So I would be happy to have a solution either for sending the messages to the console or to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a parallelization method on top of the **future** framework, e.g. **future_lapply**, **furrr**, **foreach** with **doFuture**, and soon also **pbapply** (https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply/issues/54), output from `cat()`, `print()`, `message()`, `warning()`, and so on in parallel workers are captured and truly re-outputted ("relayed") in your main R session as the parallel tasks completed.  You can read about this in https://future.futureverse.org/articles/future-2-output.html.

If you want to see *near-live* output, that is, output that is produced while the parallel tasks are still running, then you use the **progressr** package.  It is designed to send *near-live progress updates* when using Futureverse. Those updates can also include custom messages.  For examples, see https://progressr.futureverse.org/#parallel-processing-and-progress-updates.

Comment: Thank you. I see that the future framewprk might be more suited. Could you give an example how the function/messages from my reprex would work with  ˋprogressrˋ?